# scala.swing: Trying to scale images to window size, but size returns 0

Tags: swing, scala

It should probably go without saying, but I'm fairly new to swing.

I'm trying to make a simple little thing which will display two images side by side, as large as the window will allow.

In theory what happening is:

- We get an imageIcon, in this case 001.jpg.
- We figure out the ratio of width/height of the imageIcon.
- We turn the imageIcon into an image.
- We turn that image into a new correctly sized image.
- We turn that image back into an image icon.

This all breaks down because the only way I've found to get the window size is `size`, but that keeps returning 0s.

This is the code I have right now:

```
class UI extends MainFrame {
    title = "Matt's window header"
    preferredSize = new Dimension(1920, 1080)
    var imageIcon = new ImageIcon("001.jpg")
    val imgRatio = imageIcon.getIconWidth.toDouble / imageIcon.getIconHeight.toDouble
    println(size)
    pack()
    println(imgRatio)
    val image = imageIcon.getImage()
    val newimg = image.getScaledInstance(size.width, (size.width * imgRatio.toInt),  java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH)
    imageIcon = new ImageIcon(newimg)
    contents = new Label {
       icon = imageIcon
   }
}
```

As an aside, it would be great if someone could give me info about how to load a different image, instead of just 001.jpg.

Answer (score 0):

`size`is not determined at the point you are accessing it. 
However, `preferredSize`is. If you add `println(preferredSize)` you will get the Dimensions you just set.

Comment: Thanks! 
What is the best way to tell what size the window is then? I'd like to not have to assume the window is at preferred size.